# Heroku, NodeJs App, Gulp, and asset revisioning issues

Tags: node.js, heroku, gulp

I am running into a issue with asset revisioning when pushing my NodeJs app to Heroku.

I was planning on running my gulp production task in post-install. One of my tasks involves revisioning the files (app.js -> app.6789.js). This means I have to clean up the references to those files in my index.ejs. The problem is with Heroku's ephemeral filesystem (where no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted). So since I run this after the files have been written there is a big chance that the rev could be lost.

One thought was I could compile all this locally and push up the reved index.ejs, but then at least with my images they would be up there twice since I compress them etc and that increases my slug size...

Am I missing something about asset revisioning / Node / Gulp / Heroku? I can't seem to find a solution or instance of this happening to someone else which makes me believe I am setting this up wrong, which could be very true. Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the Node.js platform owner at Heroku.

Heroku splits deploys into 'build' and 'run' phases... so when you `git push` your app, you can use a package.json `postinstall` script to build whatever assets you'd like, which will be stored together in the 'slug'. The files in this slug are used for all dynos spun up afterwards.

> where no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted

I think this may be what's tripping you up. Your build runs on a single, special, temporary dyno - and then the file system that it creates is used in all subsequent, long-lasting dynos. So you can safely build assets in `postinstall` that will be used across multiple dynos and restarts.

Lots more info here:

- http://12factor.net/build-release-run
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler

Comment: Thank you this answers my question! That block of text was confusing me and your explanation/links cleared that up.